# How/where did Knuth define the famous \TeX macro?

Tags: macros, tex-core, logos

Does anyone know how Knuth originally defined the famous TeX macro `\TeX`? Specifically, I want to know *where* I can find in, say, a TeXLive set of source files, of this macro being constructed.

I'm not asking so that I can recreate it or so I can better understand macros. I'm asking because I've been studying TeX source code/the TeXbook/tex.web for a while, but I'm still confused about its programming structure. All I can really gather is that some of it is written in WEB, Pascal, something called Pascal-H, then TeXLive made WEB2C to translate it to C, etc., so I feel that a concrete identification of where `\TeX` is defined in TeX source code would be helpful in sorting this stuff out.

Comment: You mean you want the code for the macro `\TeX` or for TeX the program itself.  If it's the former, Knuth's definition is `\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}` on line 693 of [`plain.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/base/plain.tex).  If you want the source of TeX, it's [on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web).

Comment: Yes, the macro, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Though it has no relation to the definition of the macro `\TeX`, if (as you mention in the question) you're trying to study the TeX source code / tex.web, I was trying to do the same earlier and have some possibly helpful supporting material somewhere [on this page](https://shreevatsa.net/tex/program). Hmm, looking at it again, it all looks disorganized and not very helpful, but FYI just in case…

Comment: @ShreevatsaR In poking around the internet regarding TeX, I have actually already come across your site containing your notes and they're wonderful and impressive! Still parsing through it :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `\TeX` macro is defined in [`plain.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/base/plain.tex) as

```latex
\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}
```

or in LaTeX ([`ltlogos.dtx`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/9d6d680b89251e2dafaa6177d39c67e7bf4f2107/base/ltlogos.dtx#L76)) as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX\@}
```

(the difference is that LaTeX makes `\TeX` a robust macro, and adds the spacefactor correction `\@`).

You can use `\show\TeX` to see its definition in plain TeX, or in a recent LaTeX distribution, `\ShowCommand\TeX`:

```latex
> \TeX=robust macro:
->\protect \TeX  .

> \TeX =\long macro:
->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@.
<argument> \TeX  
                 
<*> \ShowCommand\TeX
                     \stop
?
```

This macro is hand-tuned to Computer Modern, so if you change fonts you might need to adapt the kerning.

Answer (score 35):

The answer by Phelype Oleinik does give the definition for the TeX logo as it appears in the file `plain.tex`, but different values were used for the various kerns for other fonts that appear in the five volumes of *Computers & Typesetting*.

Knuth wrote an article for TUGboat explaining the differences and the reasoning behind the differences, and giving the values for fonts other than `cmr` in the Computer Modern family:
["The TeX Logo in Various Fonts", TUGboat, Volume 7 (1986), No. 2, p.101](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb07-2/tb15knutlogo.pdf)

Answer (score 30):

This answer adds nothing more than Phelype and Barbara already told you about the `\TeX` macro. However, for completeness sake, I just want to point out the existence of a command line tool named `texdef` that gives you the definition of TeX macros based on the provided parameters. In this case

```
[paulo@cambridge ~] $ texdef TeX

\TeX:
macro:->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX
```

brings the original definition Phelype mentioned. By invoking the tool without any additional flags and options, `texdef` assumes TeX. If we explicitly ask for a LaTeX definition (`-t latex`),

```
[paulo@cambridge ~] $ texdef -t latex TeX

\TeX:
macro:->\protect \TeX  


\TeX :
\long macro:->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@
```

the tool gives us the robust version as defined in LaTeX.

Comment: (The last command is equivalent to `latexdef TeX`.)