# How to create a LATEX like logo using any word at hand?

Tags: macros, logos

I want to create a logo like

[image]

using the word `LECTURE`.

I tried to edit Martin's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11096/65856) but I was unable to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The design expert in me tells me this looks awful, but it will give you a start:

> [image]

There are three things you can do to make a logo like this:

- you can `\kern`, to move characters closer or further from each other;
- you can `\raise` or `\lower` characters;
- you can change their size (as the `A` in [image]).

The three above are available without driver dependent operations, like scaling or rotating.  If you want to have those too:

- you can also scale (or mirror, which is a special case of scaling, like the first `E` in [image]);
- and you can rotate, for extra wackiness :)

Here I'll stick with the first three, but the other two are not hard to apply if you so wish.

#### `\kern`ing

You can use the `\kern` primitive to move characters close to each other.  You can write `A\kern-0.5em B` to have the `B` move `0.5em` towards the `A`, partially superimposing it.  If you use a positive value, it will go further away.  The unit `em` is defined (but not exactly!) as “[roughly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=56487753#56487753) the width of an uppercase letter M in the current font”, so it is better to use `em` here as the exact amount it will move will depend on the actual width of the glyphs in the font, so if you use your symbol with a larger or smaller size, it should stay more or less correct.  Note that the exact amount of kerning [depends on the font used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570891/134574), to you might need to adjust.

#### `\raise`ing or `\lower`ing

You can move characters (boxes, actually) up or down using the `\raise` or `\lower` primitives.  The syntax is `\raise <dimension> <box>`.  The dimension is similar to `\kern`, except here you'll prefer to use the unit `ex`, defined as “roughly the height of a lowercase letter x in the current font”, so it is an indication of the height of the glyphs.  Also `\raise` (and `\lower`) need a box, so instead of `A\raise 0.5ex B` you have to write `A\raise 0.5ex\hbox{B}` to get the `B` slightly higher than the `A`.

#### Changing font size

The LaTeX logo selects the current script font size for the `A` (the same size as in math super/subscripts).  You can use the same technique, or you can use the `\relsize` package to change to a smaller or larger font size, or use the `\scalebox` command.  Though scaling might look bad if you overdo it.

I made the font size changing into a command `\logosmaller` that makes the argument with the script size font, and aligns it with the top line of other characters:

```latex
\def\logosmaller#1{%
  \hbox{\sbox\z@ T%
    \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
      \fontsize\sf@size\z@
      \math@fontsfalse\selectfont #1}\vss}}}
```

then you can use `L\logosmaller{A}` to make something similar to LaTeX.

#### Building the logo

```
\newcommand\lecture{%
  L\kern-.2em%
  \logosmaller{E}\kern-.1em%
  C\kern-.2em%
  \raise0.5ex\hbox{T}\kern-.23em%
  \hbox{U}\kern-.1em%
  \lower0.1ex\logosmaller{R}\kern-.1em%
  E\@}
```

The logo starts with `L`, then brings the next character closer by `-0.2em`.

```latex
  L\kern-.2em%
```

then it adds a smaller `E`, and brings `C` closer by `-0.1em`, and the `T` closer to `C` by `-0.2em`:

```latex
  \logosmaller{E}\kern-.1em%
  C\kern-.2em%
```

now we raise the `T` by 0.5ex, and bring the `U` and the `R` closer:

```latex
  \raise0.5ex\hbox{T}\kern-.23em%
  \hbox{U}\kern-.1em%
```

finally, make the `R` smaller and lower it, and at the end add the `E` and the spacefactor correction `\@`:

```latex
  \lower0.1ex\logosmaller{R}\kern-.1em%
  E\@
```

then add the final `E`.

---

Here's a compilable example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\logosmaller#1{%
  \hbox{\sbox\z@ T%
    \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
      \fontsize\sf@size\z@
      \math@fontsfalse\selectfont #1}\vss}}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\lecture{%
  L\kern-.2em%
  \logosmaller{E}\kern-.1em%
  C\kern-.2em%
  \raise0.5ex\hbox{T}\kern-.23em%
  \hbox{U}\kern-.1em%
  \lower0.1ex\logosmaller{R}\kern-.1em%
  E\@}

Here's a \lecture\ for you

\end{document}
```

Comment: "The design expert in me tells me this looks awful" in me too :-). But gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Just to entertain me on the first day of 2021 :D, how about this:

[image: OutputOK]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\makeatletter
\def\lecture@ssize{\larger[-3]\scshape}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lecture}{%
  \mbox{%
    L\kern-0.37em
    \raisebox{0.49ex}{\lecture@ssize e}%\kern-0.1em
    C\kern-0.53em
    \raisebox{0.49ex}{\lecture@ssize t}\kern-0.05em
    \raisebox{0.49ex}{\lecture@ssize u}\kern-0.12em%
    R\kern-0.1em
    \raisebox{0.49ex}{\lecture@ssize e}%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here's a \lecture\ for you


{\large Here's a \lecture\ for you}


{\Large Here's a \lecture\ for you}

{\LARGE Here's a \lecture\ for you}

{\huge Here's a \lecture\ for you}

{\Huge Here's a \lecture\ for you}

\end{document}
```

Adapted from an old response (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60515/7832 ) from the time I created my own logo.

Answer (score 2):

If one's too lazy to position letters by oneself and a semi-automatic alternative is needed, a broke man's solution is possible via MetaPost.

Disadvantages are: 1) because of random raising and lowering, outputs will be different, but one can choose a result and store it for later use, 3) it doesn't work well with non-ASCII string, 2) well, results are rather ugly, but beauty in the eye of the beholder.

Anyway, here's my approach:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[latex,shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\uglylogo}[2][\textwidth]{%
\begin{mpost}[name=uglylogo]
vardef myuglylogo(expr s) =
    save len; len := length s;
    save Char; picture Char[];
    save Em; Em := 0;
    save Ex;
    for i = 1 upto len:
        Char[i] := image(label((substring(i-1,i) of s), origin);)  scaled (1-uniformdeviate(0.4));
        Ex := (ypart (ulcorner Char[i])) - (ypart (llcorner Char[i]));
        draw Char[i] shifted
        if (i mod 2 = 1):
            (Em,Ex*uniformdeviate(0.35))    
        else:
            (Em,-Ex*uniformdeviate(0.35))   
        fi;
        Em := Em + (xpart (urcorner Char[i])) - (xpart (ulcorner Char[i]));  
    endfor
enddef;
myuglylogo("#2");
\end{mpost}%
\usempost[width=#1]{uglylogo}%
}
\vbox{
\hbox{\uglylogo[6cm]{LECTURE}}
\hbox{\uglylogo[6cm]{LECTURE}}
\hbox{\uglylogo[6cm]{LECTURE}}
\hbox{\uglylogo[6cm]{LECTURE}}
\hbox{\uglylogo[6cm]{LECTURE}}
\hbox{\uglylogo[6cm]{LECTURE}}
\hbox{\uglylogo[6cm]{LECTURE}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]